# How to allow a user to enter html comments

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, html-encode

Using MVC, EF 4.2. I am working on an application that has a comment section. Right now if a user enters a comment that contains HTML e.g.

```
<b>text</b>
```

and hits submit i get the message 
"A ptentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected..."

1. How do i handle html on the way into the db? Should I just strip the html? Or encode it? I tried server.htmlencode the text but i still had the same error message.

I have read a number of posts on the matter including some here at SO - [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573627/how-to-allow-simple-html-tags-in-comments-or-anywhere) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257018/making-the-blog-comments-posted-by-users-safe)

Ideally, i'd like to be able to allow a limited number of html tags such as em strong, a.  Would Anti-XSS, HTML Agility, some kind of BB code, or a markdown style editor still be the recommended way? I know Jeff has a whitelist bit of code  - however it is few yrs old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult foo()
{
}
```

or you  can decorate the model property with `AllowHtml`

```
   public class Foo
    {
        [AllowHtml]
        public string bar{ get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I looked those attributes also but wouldnt they allow the possibility of XSS and malicious code being submitted via the comment?

Comment: yup that is the trade off, if you are using the older view engine (i forgot the name) you can write `<%:Html.TextBoxFor%>` it will encode the value or if you are using razor `@` syntax it will encode the html

Comment: If you're worried about xss and other code look into [Microsoft's Anti-XSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) library

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to set the requestValidationMode in your web.config:

```
</system.web>
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

See [this link](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

MVC has an attribute that allows you to specify a property should allow html without disabling validation completely. It's still dangerous, but it can be limited to a single property so the risk can be mitigated. Here is the [MSDN article for the AllowHtmlAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). Proper usage of the attribute should be to decorate the appropriate property in your model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public MyModel()
    {

    }

    // Some other stuff in here

    [AllowHtml]
    [HttpPost]
    public string MyHtmlString { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for allow html incomments is as follows:

1. AllowHtml on the CommentText property in my comment class
2. Allow a narrow subset of tags. Use an Html Sanitizer class to scrub Html and inline script that is not allowed via a whitelist
3. Then save the result to the db as i normally would
4. At output time, use Html.Raw to show the Html in the comments